# user.groups.add(group) or group.user_set.add(user), Which is better and why ? or difference between them

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I am trying to extend django.contrib.auth and came accross adding a user into a group, which can be done in 2 ways. I was just wondering why is it like so, and what are the advantages of one over the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do the exact same thing.

A many-to-many relation consists of an intermediate table with a foreign key to both models. `user.groups.add(group)` will create an entry in that table where the foreign keys point to the `user` and `group` instances. The same happens with `group.user_set.add(user)`.

Comment: Specifically, both methods will generate SQL that is starting something like `INSERT INTO "auth_user_groups" ("user_id", "group_id") VALUES...`.